# How do I fix the indentation of selected lines in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

In [vim](http://www.vim.org/) I can use `=` to reindent badly indented lines so

```
foo;
  bar;
 baz;
```

becomes

```
foo;
bar;
baz;
```

Is there an equivalent keyboard-shortcut for visual studio? Where can I find a list of such shortcuts for future reference?

---

**Edit:** Is there a way to do fix just the horizontal indentation? There are some cases where the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> is "fixing" too much. (In the meantime I'll see if I can edit the formatting options to my satisfaction...)

Comment: [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189)

Comment: Here's a caveat for anyone else tearing their hair out dealing with the same issue as me:

Visual Studio will not fix the indentation of html elements that are nested inside of an unrecognized html element.  So if you're using a framework that lets you use non-standard elements like <tabset>, anything within <tabset> will be ignored by Visual Studio when applying the Ctrl K + Ctrl F fix.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Selecting all the text you wish to format and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> shortcut applies the indenting and space formatting.

As specified in the Formatting pane (of the language being used) in the Text Editor section of the Options dialog.

See [VS Shortcuts](https://www.dofactory.com/visual-studio-shortcuts) for more.

Comment: Note that this reformats the code, which is different from just reindenting it. As far as I know Visual Studio cannot just reindent the lines.

Comment: This doesn't work on MAC or for VS version 1.27, you need to set the shortcut yourself. Open `Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts` and search for `Reindent Lines` or `Reindent Selected Lines` and set a shortcut.

Comment: What @SvenvanZoelen mentioned really works fine in **VSCodium** `Version 1.34.0 (1.34.0)` too!

Comment: link is broken. can you replace with actual shortcuts please

Answer (score 41):

I like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which indents the whole document.

Comment: vs2019 => Ctrl+D

Comment: VS2019 Ctrl + D does duplicate for me @GuillermoVarini

Comment: Hence, the answer is not Ctrl+D.. it's Ctrl-KD ;)

Answer (score 18):

Selecting the text to fix, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> shortcut certainly works.
However, I generally find that if a particular method (for instance) has it's indentation messed up, simply removing the closing brace of the method, and re-adding, in fact fixes the indentation anyway, thereby doing without the need to select the code before hand, ergo is quicker. 
ymmv.

Answer (score 9):

> For the Mac users.

For selecting all of the code in the document  => <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

For formatting selected code => <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

To fix the indentation and formatting in all files of your solution:

1. Install the [*Format All Files*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.FormatAllFiles) extension => close VS, execute the *.vsix* file and reopen VS;
2. Menu *Tools > Options... > Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs*:

   1. Click on *Smart* (for resolving conflicts);
   2. Type the *Tab Size* and *Indent Size* you want (e.g. `2`);
   3. Click on *Insert Spaces* if you want to **replace tabs by spaces**;
3. In the *Solution Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) right click in any file and choose from the menu ***Format All Files*** (near the bottom).

This will **recursively open and save all files** in your solution, setting the indentation you defined above.

You might want to check other programming languages tabs (*Options...*) for *Code Style > Formatting* as well.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Visual Studio 2022: You can click this button to format the entire document:

[image: Toolbar button in Visual Studio]

You can also see the keyboard shortcut on hover. Note: this may apply additional formatting other than just indentation.